# varchar(255) v tinyblob v tinytext

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

My side question is there really any difference between tinyblob & tinytext?

Buy my real question is what reason, if any, would I choose varchar(255) over tinyblob or tinytext?

Answer (score 18):

Primarily [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) and memory handling/speed:

> In the following table, `M` represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. `L` represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> VARCHAR(`M`), VARBINARY(`M`):
>   `L` + 1
>   bytes if column values require 0 – 255
>   bytes,
>   `L` + 2 bytes if values may
>   require more than 255 bytes
>
> TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT:
>   `L` + 1 bytes, where `L` < 2<sup>8</sup>

Additionally, see [this](http://markmail.org/message/u5rl7bhx64jsom2l) post:

> For each table in use, MySQL allocates
>   memory for 4 rows. For each of these
>   rows CHAR(X)/VARCHAR(X) column takes
>   up the X characters.
>
> A TEXT/BLOB on the other hand is
>   represented by a 8 byte pointer + a
>   1-4 byte length (depending on the
>   BLOB/TEXT type). The BLOB/TEXT is
>   allocated dynamicly on use. This will
>   use less memory, but in some cases it
>   may fragment your memory in the long
>   run.

**Edit**: As an aside, blobs store binary data and text stores ASCII, thats the only difference between TINYBLOB and TINYTEXT.

Answer (score 5):

VARCHAR(255) is more SQL standard than tinyblob or tinytext.  So your script, and application would be more portable across database vendors.

Answer (score -8):

You can't apply CHARACTER SET to TINYTEXT, but you can to VARCHAR(255)

Comment: It's not true, you can apply character set to both VARCHAR and TINYTEXT (in mySQL), but not to TINYBLOB.