# CharField max_length 2^n vs 2^n-1

Tags: python, database, django

Why does one use max_length of CharField equal to 2^n whilst others use 2^n-1?

For example:

- in django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.models (django 1.3):

  ```
  class SpatialRefSys(models.Model, SpatialRefSysMixin):
      srtext = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
  ```
- in django_openid_auth.models (djano-openid-auth 0.3):

  ```
  class Nonce(models.Model):
      server_url = models.CharField(max_length=2047)
  ```

Although it is not scientific measure, [2048 seems to be more popular than 2047](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=charfield%20max_length%202047&word2=charfield%20max_length%202048), but [255 is more popular than 256](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=charfield%20max_length%20255&word2=charfield%20max_length%20256). Django documentation says, that in MySQL [max_length is restricted to 255 characters if you are using unique=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#character-fields). But why would I use 2^n-1 instead od 2^n in other cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've mostly got it.  It's not just the unique=True argument for 255, it's also that strings up to 255 long can [sometimes be stored more efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340639/why-historically-do-people-use-255-not-256-for-database-field-magnitudes/2340662#2340662).

So the answer is that there is *maybe* a point to doing it for 255 vs. 256, but for other lengths it's very likely to be pointless.  Picking power-of-two lengths to begin with is often not done for a scientific reason (most of us haven't actually benchmarked that our 512-long field made our application run measurably faster than a 513-long field).

That said, there may be application-specific cases where the Django application is a frontend to a C application, where having N^2-1 strings is useful further down the line to efficiently store the additional terminating `\0` byte.