# Best data type for storing strings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the best data type to be used when storing strings, like a first name? I've seen varchar and nvarchar both used. Which one is better? Does it matter?

I've also heard that the best length to use is 255, but I don't know why. Is there a specific length that is preferred for strings?

Comment: Any performance difference when using varchar or nvarchar over char(256) ?

Comment: @Matt: If you use char, your column will always take up enough space for the number of characters specified. This can give you a very slight speed advantage, but unless you know that your data will rarely vary in length you'll end up wasting a lot of space. Best to go with varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

nvarchar stores unicode character data which is required if you plan to store non-English names. If it's a web application, I highly recommend using nvarchar even if you don't *plan* on being international. The downside is that it consumes twice as much space, 16-bits per character for nvarchar and 8-bits per character for varchar.

Answer (score 6):

> What's the best data type to be used
> when storing strings, like a first
> name? I've seen varchar and nvarchar
> both used. Which one is better? Does
> it matter?

See [What is the difference between nchar(10) and varchar(10) in MSSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-nchar10-and-varchar10-in-mssql)

If you need non-ASCII characters, you have to use `nchar`/`nvarchar`.  If you don't, then you may want to use `char`/`varchar` to save space.

Note that this issue is specific to MS SQL Server, <s>which doesn't have good support for UTF-8</s>.  In other SQL implementations that do, you can use Unicode strings with no extra space requirements (for English).

**EDIT:** Since this answer was originally written, SQL Server 2019 (15.x) finally introduced [UTF-8 support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580).  You may want to consider using it as your default database text encoding.

> I've also heard that the best length
> to use is 255, but I don't know why.

See [Is there a good reason I see VARCHAR(255) used so often (as opposed to another length)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217466/is-there-a-good-reason-i-see-varchar255-used-so-often-as-opposed-to-another-le)

> Is there a specific length that is
> preferred for strings?

If you data has a well-defined maximum limit (e.g., 17 characters for a VIN),  then use that.

OTOH, if the limit is arbitrary, then choose a generous maximum size to avoid rejecting valid data.  In SQL Server, you may want to consider the [900-byte maximum size of index keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar means you can save unicode character inside it. there is 2GB limit for nvarchar type. if the field length is more than 4000 characters, an overflow page is used. smaller fields means one page can hold more rows which increase the query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for small strings use `nvarchar(n)`, which supports Unicode characters. The string is [compressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation) when used with row or page compression (at least one of which is generally desirable).

Large strings need `nvarchar(max)`, which Unicode compression does not support.

For special-case scenarios when your data set never uses Unicode characters, `varchar(n)` and `varchar(max)` restrict the string type of one byte per character.

If you know the max length (`n`) is less than 256, SQL Server only needs to use 1 byte to store the string length. This reduces storage space by about half a percent compared a string type whose max length is just over 255.